# Expected element before end of the content. Soap XSD validation

Tags: soap, xsd, soapui

I am using soap and i have response from service. I click right mouse button and choose validate and i have errors 'Expected element xxx before the end of the content..."

In the xsd schema i have already

> elementFormDefault="qualified"

AdditionalAtribute as name says is nullable so sometimes it has value but not always. When it has value everything is ok but when it is null my response validation gives me this communicate.

This is what my XSD fragment looks like:

```
       <xsd:element name="listOfThings" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
               <xsd:complexType>
                 <xsd:sequence>
                
                <xsd:element name="thingCategory" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="thingName" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="thingValue" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xsd:element name="additionalAttubute" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                
                  </xsd:sequence>
               </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
```

XML example

```
<tns:listOfThings>
    <tns:thing>
        <tns:thingCategory>CATEGORY</tns:thingCategory>
        <tns:thingName>NAME</tns:thingName>
        <tns:thingValue>A</tns:thingValue>
    </tns:thing>
    <tns:thing>
        <tns:thingCategory>CATEGORY2</tns:thingCategory>
        <tns:thingName>NAME2</tns:thingName>
        <tns:thingValue>B</tns:thingValue>
        <tns:additionalAttribute>C</tns:additionalAttribute>
    </tns:thing>
</tns:listOfThings>
```

Comment: Can you also add a fragment of XML that demonstrates the issue?   Note minoccurs="0" is not the same as allowing the field to be null.

Comment: <tns:listOfThings>
            <tns:thing>
               <tns:thingCategory>CATEGORY</tns:thingCategory>
               <tns:thingName>NAME</tns:thingName>
               <tns:thingValue>A</tns:thingValue>
            </tns:thing>
            <tns:thing>
               <tns:thingCategory>CATEGORY2</tns:thingCategory>
               <tns:thingName>NAME2</tns:thingName>
               <tns:thingValue>B</tns:thingValue>
               <tns:additionalAttribute>C</tns:additionalAttribute>
            </tns:thing>
</tns:listOfThings>

@Dijkgraaf thanks for your response. :)

Comment: If there are validation errors, the it should be reported as defect in the application / service and get resolved with the service provider.

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple mismatches between your schema and your XML

1. You have actually have a node `things` under `listOfThings` that should have the maxoccurs unbounded rather than `listOfThings`
2. additionalAttubute in the schema <> additionalAttribute in the XML, a spelling mistake in the schema?

Below is what your schema should look like to match that XML

```
        <tns:element name="listOfThings">
          <tns:complexType>
            <tns:sequence>
              <tns:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="thing">
                <tns:complexType>
                  <tns:sequence>
                    <tns:element minOccurs="0" name="thingCategory" type="tns:string" />
                    <tns:element minOccurs="0" name="thingName" type="tns:string" />
                    <tns:element minOccurs="0" name="thingValue" type="tns:string" />
                    <tns:element minOccurs="0" name="additionalAttribute" type="tns:string" />
                  </tns:sequence>
                </tns:complexType>
              </tns:element>
            </tns:sequence>
          </tns:complexType>
        </tns:element>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with empty element:

```
<tns:listOfThings>
<tns:thing>
    <tns:thingCategory>CATEGORY</tns:thingCategory>
    <tns:thingName>NAME</tns:thingName>
    <tns:thingValue>A</tns:thingValue>
    <tns:additionalAttribute></tns:additionalAttribute>
</tns:thing>
<tns:thing>
    <tns:thingCategory>CATEGORY2</tns:thingCategory>
    <tns:thingName>NAME2</tns:thingName>
    <tns:thingValue>B</tns:thingValue>
    <tns:additionalAttribute>C</tns:additionalAttribute>
</tns:thing>
</tns:listOfThings>
```

Comment: With the schema given, having the element not there is also correct  as per minoccurs=0.   For a string it is valid to be empty, however for some other types that would fail validation unless the field has been defined with nillable="true" and in the XML have xsi:nil="true".  Also that wasn't the issue for the OP, see my answer.